# Unable to uninstall Sitecore 9.1 and getting "No registration found for extension 'RemoveSQLDatabase' of type 'Task'"

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

I was following Quick Installation Guide available [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Initial_Release.aspx) to uninstall my fresh Sitecore 9.1 instance.

It says in chapter `4.2. Uninstall the XP Single topology` this:

---

To uninstall any of the Sitecore XP topologies, change the 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration cmdlet to Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration.

For example: Change
`Install-SitecoreConfiguration @XP1Parameters *>&1 | Tee-Object XP1-
SingleDeveloper.log`
to
`Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration @XP1Parameters *>&1 | Tee-Object XP1-
SingleDeveloper-Uninstall.log`

Run the script and the topology is removed.

---

I have done exactly that:

[image]

This is the exact code:

```
#Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper.log

# Uncomment the below line and comment out the above if you want to remove the XP0 SingleDeveloper Config
Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper-Uninstall.log
```

I have uncommented what was needed to and commented what I had to.

But getting this error:

> Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration : No registration found for extension
>   'RemoveSQLDatabase' of type 'Task'. At
>   C:\ResourceFiles\03_UninstallSitecore_XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:77
>   char:1
>   + Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Obj ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:00:01
>
> MapTasks : No registration found for extension
>   'RemoveSQLDatabase' of type 'Task'. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:453
>   char:28
>   + ... sksConfig = MapTasks -InputObject $rawConfig -TasksToExecute $tasksTo ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,MapTasks

This is how it looks in Powershell in full length:

[image]

Any thoughts?

I have already run `Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework` to have up to date SIF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the SQLServer module.

Either run the `prerequisites.json` file which will install that and any missing prerequisites or:

`Install-Module -Name SQLServer` if you are just missing the SQL server module.

Comment: I have already run prerequisites.json during installation. I have received this error when running command suggested by you in your answer: PackageManagement\Install-Package : A command with name 'Decode-SqlName' is already available on this system. This
module 'SqlServer' may override the existing commands. If you still want to install this module 'SqlServer', use
-AllowClobber parameter.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1772 char:21.....

Comment: My guess is that you have SQL installed locally on your machine? This isn't a problem, however an old SQL module called SQLPS will be there that causes that error. 
I would suggest you run two things. Your PowerShellGet module is out of date, so run "Update-Module -name PowerShellGet" and then 
"Install-Module -Name SQLServer -AllowClobber -Force" which will override the SQLPS module.

Comment: Thanks for helping me Richard. At the end I have run prerequisites first, close Powershell command window and rerun instainstall script. Seems that uninstall script did not recognized new SQLServer module ...

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this by:

1. Rerunning `Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\Prerequisites.json` . Not sure why first run was not successful. Could be that I have forgotten to run it before installing first Sitecore 9.1 instance... Can't remember precisely as it was during release night :)
2. Closing Powershell command prompt (to make changes / updates in step 1 take in account)
3. Rerunning uninstall ps1 script as mentioned in answer

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Couto shared a different solution on his [blog](https://letsdositecore.wordpress.com/2018/12/04/the-install-sitecoreconfiguration-command-was-found-in-the-module-sitecoreinstallframework-but-the-module-could-not-be-loaded-for-more-information-run-import-module-sitecoreinstallframework/) that has also worked for me. Some computers seems to have access right issues.

When calling the SIF command, use the `ByPass` `ExecutionPolicy`.

Examples:

- `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\Prerequisites.json`
- `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration @XP1Parameters *>&1 | Tee-Object XP1-SingleDeveloper-Uninstall.log`